# Reactjs keeps throwing error "TypeError: this.goActive is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is used to detect if the user is active or not. But as soon as I move my mouse it throws an error `TypeError: this.goActive is not a function` from `resetTimer(e)` yet if I run `resetTimer(e)` by itself I get my "oy" in the console.
here is my code:

```
var timeoutID;
class App extends Component {


 setup() {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.resetTimer, false);
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", this.resetTimer, false);
    window.addEventListener("keypress", this.resetTimer, false);
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.resetTimer, false);
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", this.resetTimer, false);
    window.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", this.resetTimer, false);

    this.startTimer();
}


 startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(this.goInactive, 2000);
}

 resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    this.goActive();
}

 goInactive() {
     console.log("gah");
}

 goActive() {
    console.log("oy");
    this.startTimer();
}

render() {
    this.setup()
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of `resetTimer` is the control it is being invoked from in the callback, the window in your case.

You need to bind your function to the correct scope:

```
this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
```

in class constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
    // and all the other class methods
  }

  // here go method declarations
}
```

alternatively you can use arrow syntax (in ES6), so you reset timer becomes:

```
class App extends Component {
  resetTimer = (e) => {
    // code 
  }

  // and other method declarations
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to bind the context of `this` in `resetTimer` to your component. 
Read more in the official React documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html